# How do I maximise CSS height in DIV in jsfiddle?

Tags: css

I have the following HTML and CSS :

```
<div id="a">
</div>

#a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/9zwsk6bb/

I would like the height to fill the total height exactly of the outer panel without using something like flexbox. Is it possible in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but for that, you need to set the parent elements `height`, because when you want the element's `height` to be `100%` of the parent, then 100% of what? So, you need to have something like

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Note that if you have a wrapper element for `#a`, then you need to set some `height` for that element as well.